# Is it possible to list COM objects by namespace and class name?

Tags: windows, com, batch-file

From a batch file, before a user installs something, I need to verify that he has not registered other CLSIDs with a given namespace and class name. Is this possible ? My understanding is that this is the ProgID. I know the ProgID is not required and might be missing for some COM objects, but where it exists, I would like to check it.

I can do that visually via regedit but that obviously does not serve my purpose here.

Comment: whatever you can do visually via regedit should be possible to acomplish with the 'reg' command, just read the progID (if exists) with 'reg query' an then query the progID. i would post more details but unfortunally i dont have a windows system at hand atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through all of the CLSIDs with a ProgID key and check if they match the specified string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "xLast="
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in ('reg query HKCR\CLSID /s /f ProgID /k /e /ve') do (
    rem echo(%%C
    if "%%~C" EQU "Enter ProgID to match on here" echo Found Match: !xLast!
    set "xLast=%%A %%B %%C"
)

endlocal
pause
```